# 404 Error using Github Pages and Three.js

Tags: node.js, github, three.js, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I am failing to deploy a simple website using Github Pages and the three.js library. There is successful functionality running the local repository in its' base state.

Once attempting to deploy via Github Pages, I am thrown a 404 error after following what I found to be the most common workflow -

1. create a /dist folder,
2. place the necessary files in it, (index.html, styles.css, main.js, assets, etc.)
3. deploy within a secondary branch 'gh-pages'.

I have redirected .js and .css references in the index to regard this change, though I am still receiving a 404 error.

The website was created using vite.js

What are some steps I could take to help aid this problem? I have rebuilt from scratch and used several references but cannot seem to solve this issue.

[Here is the repository](https://github.com/autumngreenbean/portfolio/tree/gh-pages)

*Edit: I have configured the repository successfully with Github Pages and it is indicated as live.

Comment: one thing, you can only deploy a repo to GitHub pages if its name is something like this [username].github.io

Comment: @SameerWaseem The repository is deployed via Github Pages successfully from what I can tell. 'Page' section of settings indicates that it is live and is hosted in the format you mention.

Comment: Where are you loading the three.js library from? `import * as THREE from 'three';` doesn't point anywhere, since `three` doesn't exist in your repository.

Comment: The docs suggest something like this: `import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';`

Comment: Also btw, I am not receiving a 404 on your entire website, only the canvas part is broken. [Here is the URL to the deployment](https://autumngreenbean.github.io/portfolio/)

Comment: @MahanLamee Aha! That makes complete sense. I have made changes to the index in both branches, but the canvas is still failing to show. However, as you mention there is no longer a 404 error which is great.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) is the easiest way. Here are the steps I take:

1. In the project's terminal, run `npm install gh-pages`
2. Under "scripts" in your package.json, add a script for 'deploy.' Like this: `"deploy": gh-pages -d dist`
3. Build your project (`npm run build`) & make sure you have a GitHub repo.
4. Now, you can run `npm run deploy` in the terminal, which will set up your project in Git Hub Pages.

Running `npm run deploy` automatically creates a branch called gh-pages. It also automatically sets up your GitHub Pages settings to reference this branch.

[Here is a Loom video](https://www.loom.com/share/1d9a06ec11f542e5861ef7e85e38e912) of me successfully deploying a new Three.js/Vite project to GitHub pages. I go through each of the steps I listed above. You may also reference my repo [here](https://github.com/jessachalla/threejs-scroller-gh-pages-demo).

Hope this helps!